# how to manually install Firefox plugins, ubuntu 20

Tags: firefox, plugins

Firefox is not recognizing some file extensions ( ie: RAR files), so every time I download one it waits with a dialogue box asking what I want to open it with. It will not just save the file.

There is no RAR option in about:plugins, how do I manually add a plugin/extension so I can tell Firefox what to do with it, and other file types that aren't in there?

Thanks!

Comment: Please be precise with release names; Ubuntu 20 is not a real release; closest to it would be Ubuntu Core 20 - so you're asking about a *snap* only server install? (20 is a *year* format used by *snap* only Ubuntu products, the *deb* based releases are all *year.month* in format)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [rar unpacker](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/unrar) to the system. Then it will be integrated into FileRoller or Engrampa.

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

then try to open RAR-file using default system-define application.

Comment: Thank you guys. Ubuntu version is 20.04.3 LTS. Is there no way to define your own extensions?? That is crazy to require installation of software, just to control the browser behaviour. All I want to do is save the file without being held up by dozens of prompt windows, while the files sit in /temp waiting for a response.